# How do I turn on my iPhone 4 if the home or power button doesn't work and connecting to a power source doesn't either?

Tags: iphone

I've got an iPhone 4 and the lock (power) button and the home button doesn't work. My phone won't turn on and I've tried plugging it in to a power source but it still hasn't done anything. Can anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turning phone on if lock button is broken?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87913/turning-phone-on-if-lock-button-is-broken)

Comment: While I agree to the answer given already that a device will always turn on when it is connected to power, if you state that it does not, it may be hanging in its standby mode. This will also make the Home and Sleep/Wake buttons appear that they don't work. If you're just assuming that those buttons do not work, you can try holding both of them simultaneously for about 6-10 seconds. If the battery icon or Apple logo comes back, it was simply stuck. Otherwise, follow the answer given already and send it in for repairs.

Answer (score 2):

If an iPhone is off, and you connect it to a power source (either a charger or computer), it will **always turn on**. !!!

If that is not working then something more serious is going on. Bring it in for repair.

Just in case it is locked-up, try holding the Home button for 30 seconds, but that might be a fruitless exercise.